# Talend Data warehousing tool

Tags: mysql, database, data-warehouse, talend

Ques: I have two database one is client's database(live database) and another is mine.I am using MySQL database. I should not access client's database directly so I created my own database. By using 'Talend' data warehousing tool I created job for each table and by executing all jobs I can get all updated data from client's database(live database) to my database. I need to execute these jobs manually for getting updated data into my Database, But my question is: is there any process which will automatically remind me, when client insert or update data on there data base so I can execute those jobs manually to get updated data into my database ?? or if client update their any database table so automatically associated job will Execute/Run ?? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up a database trigger that somehow notifies the Talend job and runs it. To do this you'd typically call the job as a web service using a stored procedure or user defined function. [This link](http://open-bi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/call-restful-web-services-from-mysql.html) shows a typical way that a web service may be called on an update trigger for example.

If your source data tables are large, rather than extracting all of the data from the table and then I guess dropping your table and recreating you could use a tMysqlCDC component to only affect changes. The built in tutorial for the component looks like it pretty much covers a useful example of this in practice. If you are seeing regular changes in the source database this could make your job much more performant.

If you have absolutely no access to your client's database then you could alternatively just run the job with some scheduler. The Enterprise versions of Talend come with the Talend Administration Console that allows you to set CRON triggers for a job and could easily be set to run every minute or any other interval (not seconds). Alternatively you could use your operating systems scheduling system to run the job at your desired intervals.

Comment: For that you need to use "Build Job"/"Export Job" feature of talend, then you'll have a nice .bat / .sh script which can be triggeret with your OS scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify your clients database (i.e. add triggers), and there  is no other way to identify changed records (i.e. some kind of audit table) then you're our of luck.